# How to pass env vars to a MultibranchPipelineJob created by Jenkins Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a [MultibranchPipelineJob](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.multibranchPipelineJob) with Jenkins Job DSL. I want to pass some environment variables to the job, but I can't figure out how to do that from the [documentation](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#).

Answer (score 4):

MultibranchPipeline Job no longer support parameters

You can use Folder Properties Plugin to set your Env variables, which can be accessed by all the jobs within that folder. https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-properties/

However, the MultiBranch pipeline job has a lot of performance issues so we moved away from multibranch pipeline jobs. We wrote a DSL job that would act as a multibranch pipeline job - which will scan through the git branches and create Simple pipeline jobs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You pass them as parameters like this:

```
parameters {
    stringParam("MyVariable1", "my-value1")
    stringParam("MyVariable2", "${my-dynamic-value2}")
}
```

Then consume them in the job using parameters or environment (both work equally) as this:

```
echo "my vars are ${parameters.MyVariable1} or ${env.MyVariable2}"
```

Comment: MultibranchPipeline Job no longer support parameters

Comment: @Dinesh Do you know how to pass env variable if `parameters` are no longer supported?

Comment: @xbmono - You can use Folder Properties Plugin to set your Env variables, which can be accessed by all the jobs within that folder. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Folder+Properties+Plugin

We actually no longer use MultiBranch pipeline job. We wrote a DSL job that would act as a multibranch pipeline job - which will look through the git branches and create Simple pipeline jobs as needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks... that actually helps... but you mentioned something more interesting, can you share the DSL job that acts as the multibranch job? I may use that instead. Thanks again

Comment: @xbmono, hmm.. Our job does lot more than just polling for branches and our repo is not public. But I'll see if I can create something for you. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Dinesh comment should be the answer to this question.